# Explicit formulation of the role of eigenvectors of the matrix of a linear time-invariant filter

Tags: filters, discrete-signals

At [this point](https://youtu.be/YfmkNaRq9yc?t=1051) in a lecture by MIT Professor Strang the idea of gaining insight into a filter by studying its eigenvectors is introduced. The idea is clear with the example chosen in the lecture: an signal-averaging 2-tap filter (running average) expressed in matrix form as

$$F=\tiny \begin{bmatrix}
&&\ddots&\ddots&&&&&&&\\&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&\\
&&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&&\\
&&&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&&\\
&&&&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\ddots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

where the vector $\small\begin{bmatrix}\cdots,1,1,1,1,\cdots\end{bmatrix}^\top$ as an input (corresponding to a frequency of $\omega =0$) is passed unaltered - as it corresponds to a low-pass filter - and hence, it is an eigenvector of $F$ with eigenvector $1.$ And, similarly, the alternating vector $\small\begin{bmatrix}\cdots,-1,1,-1,1,\cdots\end{bmatrix}^\top$ (corresponding to a frequency of $\omega =\pi$) is in the null space of $F.$

The idea is thus exemplified, and the intuition is left implicit.

> I am asking here for an explicit statement and explanation of the importance and role of the study of eigenvectors in the setting of filters.

---

Possibly the answer may lie in the generalization to the effect of the matrix on the pure frequencies

$$x_\omega(n)=e^{i\omega n},$$

i.e.

$$\frac 1 2 e^{i\omega n} + \frac 1 2 e^{i\omega (n-1)}=\underset{\text{eigenvalue}}{\underbrace{\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}\,\right )}}\;\underset{\text{eigenvector}}{\underbrace{\,e^{i\omega n}}}$$

If this is the correct idea, the matrix expression would be

$$\tiny \begin{bmatrix}
&&\ddots&\ddots&&&&&&&\\&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&\\
&&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&&\\
&&&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&&\\
&&&&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\ddots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}\small
\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots\\
e^{i\omega (n-2)}\\
e^{i\omega (n-1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+2)}\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}=\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots\\
e^{i\omega (n-2)}\\
e^{i\omega (n-1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+2)}\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}$$

with $H(\omega) = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}$ corresponding to the frequency response function, which generalizes to

$$H(\omega) = \sum_{k=0}^N h(k) e^{-ik\omega}$$

with $h(k)$ corresponding to the $k$-th coefficient of the $N$ number of taps, and $H(\omega)$ being the Fourier transform. The actual filter being the convolution $y(n) =\sum_{k=0}^n h[k]\, x[n-k].$

In the case of $N=2,$

$$\tiny \begin{bmatrix}
&&\ddots&\ddots&&&&&&&\\&&&h(0)&h(1)&&&\\
&&&&h(0)&h(1)&&&&\\
&&&&&h(0)&h(1)&&&&\\
&&&&&&h(0)&h(1)&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\ddots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}\small
\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots\\
e^{i\omega (n-2)}\\
e^{i\omega (n-1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+2)}\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}=\tiny\left(h(0)\,e^{-i\,0\,\omega} + h(1)\, e^{-i\,1\,\omega}\right)
\small\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots\\
e^{i\omega (n-2)}\\
e^{i\omega (n-1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+2)}\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Following up on the first comment...

$$\left(\tiny\begin{bmatrix}
\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2\\&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2\\
&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2\\
&&&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
-
\tiny\begin{bmatrix}
\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}\right)\\
&\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}\right)\\
&&\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}\right)\\
&&&\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 e^{-i\omega}\right)\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}
e^{i\omega (n-2)}\\
e^{i\omega (n-1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+1)}\\
e^{i\omega (n+2)}\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Considerig your F matrix, how do you compute its (matrix) eigenvalue and eigenvectors based on $|F - \lambda I|=0$?

Comment: @Fat32 I added this calculation, which seems to show that the idea of the effect on pure frequencies is indeed the case. I still think that some sort of summary in English would be pertinent as a formal answer...

Comment: Hello... What I meant was, can you show that the eigenvalues of the F matrix are = $0.5 + 0.5 e^{j\omega}$ without assuming that they are the eigenvalues? Your added calculations indicate that  $0.5 + 0.5 e^{j\omega }$ are eigenvalues of F (for the eigenvectors $e^{j \omega n}$) but not the converse; i.e. do not assume that $e^{j\omega n}$ as eigenvectors and $0.5 + 0.5 e^{j\omega}$ as the corresponding eigenvalues? may be I missed a point.